# Regular Expression for this these characters : BASIC-GT-02-0078276

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression for these characters. The first 5 characters "BASIC" is fixed for every string, followed by a "-", followed by next 2 characters which should be Alphabets, then 2 numbers and then 7 numbers.

I formed this one, but it not working.

```
^"BASIC"{5}[-]{1}[A-Z]{2}[-]{1}[0-9]{2}[-]{1}[0-9]{7}
```

some valid matches : BASIC-KH-67-8743532, BASIC-RF-00-2245890..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use:

```
^BASIC-[A-Z]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{7}$
```

This pattern says to match:

- `^` from the start of the string
- `BASIC` match literal string "BASIC"
- `[A-Z]{2}` match 2 uppercase letters
- `-` hyphen
- `[0-9]{2}` match 2 digits
- `-` hyphen
- `[0-9]{7}` match 7 digits
- `$` end of the string